# Google Material Design Icons - Which file ( out of 18dp, 24,36 & 48 ) to be used from respective drawable folder

Tags: android, material-design

Google Material Design Icons  https://github.com/google/material-design-icons  , noticed under each folder i.e. ( drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc.. ) 
there is 4 set of files at least.. as shown below..

I am wondering while using them in layout as ImageButton, which file should be referenced in  `android:src` property, and what would be logic behind it. Assumption is app must support 4 inch, 5 inch and 10 inch screen size. May be someone explain the purpose of these 4 types of files.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 111 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_black_18dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121  94 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_black_24dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 105 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_black_36dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 111 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_black_48dp.png

-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121  81 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-mdpi/ic_menu_black_18dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121  82 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-mdpi/ic_menu_black_24dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121  94 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-mdpi/ic_menu_black_36dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121  99 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-mdpi/ic_menu_black_48dp.png

-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121  94 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xhdpi/ic_menu_black_18dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121  99 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xhdpi/ic_menu_black_24dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 111 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xhdpi/ic_menu_black_36dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 116 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xhdpi/ic_menu_black_48dp.png

-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 105 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_black_18dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 111 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_black_24dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 117 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_black_36dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 127 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_black_48dp.png

-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 111 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_menu_black_18dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 116 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_menu_black_24dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 127 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_menu_black_36dp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 girishkhatri 197121 129 Jul 26 22:27 ./navigation/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_menu_black_48dp.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the details and purpose of the Icon at https://google.github.io/material-design-icons and https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html 24 being default

> Sizing
>
> Although the icons in the font can be scaled to any size, in accordance with >material design icons guidelines, we recommend them to be shown in either 18, 24, 36 or 48px. The default being 24px

Answer (score 0):

The [Material Design](https://material.google.com/) and [Google Design](https://design.google.com/) sites are useful resources for guidelines regarding UI design. Following the patterns suggested there will help you create an app which is consistent with modern Android design philosophy. Particularly, check out the design guidelines for [Icons](https://material.google.com/style/icons.html) and for [Imagery](https://material.google.com/style/imagery.html).

Note that images sizes are typically measured in "device independent pixels" which is abbreviated "dp" or sometimes "dip". This usually allows us to ignore the physical sizes of different devices.

Comment: Thanks, but I posted this question only after going through https://material.google.com/ . Probably getting too specific.. but need to understand logic behind it for effective use in app..

Comment: @Girish I am a developer, not a designer. I am trying to figure out Material Design myself.